# Passing date as command line arguments in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have my below query in `test1.hql file`. I am trying to pass the `date (dt)` as the command line argument.

```
select * from lip_data_quality where dt = '${hiveconf: start_date}';
```

So whenever I try to run the above `test1.hql` file from shell prompt like this-

```
 hive -f hivetest1.hql -hiveconf start_date=20120709
```

I get zero records back. But the data is there in that table for that particular date. Why is it so? Something wrong I am doing?

Can anyone help me out here? I was following [Bejoy's Article](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/10/include-values-during-execution-time-in.html)

I am working `Hive 0.6`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eliminate the space between hiveconf: and start_date.

This may only be for string types, but Hive is picky in this respect.